# JQuery plugin issue with IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a plugin which records user action on any website. 
The actions are recorded in a different window of the same browser. 
For IE, it works properly on all sites except the ones having Iframe. 
The script gets blocked on the sites having Iframes with the following error: 
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

Its a self created plugin.

The error is on window.open
It does not open a new window properly

Below is the snippet of the plugin.

```
newwindow = window.open("", "ScriptGen", "menubar=0,directories=0,toolbar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=450,height=250,titlebar=0"); 

newwindow.document.write('<title>New Console</title>');
```

Using alert(window) displays "[object Window] on all sites..but on sites having iframes, it displays only "[object]"

Please guide.

Comment: To start off with, what's the name of the plugin?

Comment: Its a self created plugin.

Comment: IE? is it on every version of it or some specific versions?

Comment: yes... it's called same origin policy. basically if the page ins't on the same domain/url path you can't touch it or do anything with it. The only way you could do something with it is with a behind the scenes proxy. http://ternarylabs.com/2011/03/27/secure-cross-domain-iframe-communication/ or use a solution like http://www.staticapps.org/articles/cross-domain-requests-with-cors

Comment: I tried both but its not working,I am not able to access nethng from the newwindow,Neither changing domain of the original window works.Is there any other solution?

Comment: can you create jsfiddle like example ?

Comment: Cant create a jsfiddle as its an external plug in to the broswer.Its like selenium ide.Opens a window wenever a site is opened n records user activity on that site in the new window.Works great in Firefox n chrome.But in ie it does not works for websites having Iframes.Cannot Access document object of the new window hence changing it's domain is not an option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me...

```
try{
           newwindow = window.open("", "ScriptGen", "menubar=0,directories=0,toolbar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=450,height=250,titlebar=0");
            console.log(newwindow.document);
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log("Error catched");
            newwindow.close();
            useDomain = true;
            var domain = document.domain;
            newwindow = window.open("javascript:document.write('<script>document.domain=\"" + document.domain + "\"</script>')", "ScriptGen", "menubar=0,directories=0,toolbar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=450,height=250,titlebar=0");
    }
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what version of jQuery are you using, but I think you should update to 1.11.0:

https://jsfiddle.net/j3LaC/ - try this with 1.10.1 (not working), and with 1.11.0 (working)

HTML:

```
<div id="body"></div>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Submit iframe"/>
```

JavaScript:

```
var iframe = $("<iframe></iframe>").appendTo("#body")[0];
var doc = iframe.document;
var content = '<form method="get"><input name="hidden" type="hidden" value="123"/></form>';
doc = iframe.contentDocument;
doc.writeln(content);
doc.close();

$('input#button').click(function () {
    $('iframe').contents().find('form')[0].submit();
});
```

CSS:

```
iframe {
    height: 300px;
    width : 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I tried it but even this doesnt seem to solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Banish the iframes before running your plug-in

```
function banish() {
    $('iframe').remove();
}
```